# Run bin files on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sqlite

I'm trying to run SQLiteStudio on Ubuntu. I'm getting error when I try to run it with terminal:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ sqlitestudio-2.0.22.bin
sqlitestudio-2.0.22.bin: command not found
```

I tried other sqlite managers but SQLiteStudio has more options, I've used it on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a ./ in front of the command

```
./sqlitestudio-2.0.22.bin
```

Comment: Or temporarily append the working directory to the path with `export PATH=.:$PATH` if you don't want to type ./ everytime.